# Is it possible to create a soap-based websocket connection to a WCF service using a plain netHttpBinding from a browser?

Tags: wcf, websocket

The JavaScript WebSocket constructor supports specifying which protocol to use:

i.e.

`ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:999/something', [list of sub-protocols]);`

I take this to mean that a JavaScript websocket client could be built that consumes `SOAP`. Is this correct? What protocols can be passed in the `[list of sub-protocols]` array? (I can't find a list of these)

I am able to consume the WCF binding (`netHttpBinding`) from a client console app, but with the JavaScript I get the error:

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

**Is it possible to consume a WCF-hosted websocket endpoint using the `netHttpBinding` endpoint?** I know this is possible when specifying a custom binding. But I would prefer to parse the SOAP in the browser in this case. My configuration for the binding looks like this:

```
<netHttpBinding>
    <binding name="netHttpBinding" messageEncoding="Text">
        <webSocketSettings transportUsage="Always" createNotificationOnConnection="true"/>
    </binding>
</netHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Why a vote to close?